# How to display two object fields into a single pageblock in visual force page

Tags: dynamic-visualforce

I have two objects - object A with fields "Name, Number and Quantity", And object B with fields "Amount, Order_*c and Units*_c". There is a lookup relationship between the two objects with field name Inventory__c.

My question is: can we bring those two object fields into a single page block in a visual force page? If so, how to write the SOQL query for getting all records?

Comment: Yes. This is why we are using controllers most of the time with a VF page. In which object your `Inventory__c` field sits on?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [Relationship Queries](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) which feel a bit strange if you ave a background in SQL.

In this case (and assuming `Inventory__c` is on `ObjectB__c` and the default names for the relationship `ObjectBs` has been used):

```
public ObjectA__c[] objectAs {
    get {
        if (objectAs == null) {
            objectAs = [
                    select Name, Number, Quantity,
                            (select Amount, Order__c, Units__c from ObjectBs__r)
                    from ObjectA__c
                    where ...
                    ];
        }
        return objectAs;
    }
    private set;
}
```

In your page block, each instance of the `objectAs`collection has a reference called `ObjectBs__r` which is a collection of `ObjectB__c`.

Answer (score 0):

Look into wrapper classes.

```
public class vfpage{

   public objWrapper records(){
      get{
      //populate wrapper with data
      objWrapper o = New ObjWrapper(OBJADATA, OBJBDATA);
      return o;
      }

      private set;
   }

   Public class objWrapper{

     public objA {get;set;}
     public objB {get;set;}

     public objWrapper(ObjA a, ObjB b){
       objA = a;
       objB = b;
     }



  }

}
```

Then use {!records.XXXXX} as your variable.

Modification to this will need to be made but this will give you a start